Ramban on Moshiach's immortality
I heard on Shiurim that the Ramban stated that death has no power over Moshiach ben David? Where does he say this?
Is it is his Sefer Geulah?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

According to the Ramban, there will be no death at all after the Resurrection:

ועל כן נאמין אנחנו במה שאמרו (סנהדרין צב א') מתים שעתיד הקדוש ברוך הוא
להחיות שוב אינן חוזרין לעפרם... ושגור בפיהם זיכרונם לברכה כמו שאמרו
בכל המדרשות ובתלמוד "למען ייטב לך" לעולם שכולו טוב "והארכת ימים" לעולם
שכולו ארוך רוצה לומר שכל הזוכים לו ארוכי הימים הם שאין בו המות


This doesn't address the question
